# Shower door rollers are offset by 4cm - is this normal or has someone bodged it?

Tags: shower

Our shower door seems to be a bit of a bodge, or I'm searching for the wrong thing as I'm trying to replace the broken wheels on the top and bottom runners.

Simply the top wheels are on an attachment which extends from the top of the shower door, isn't inline with it but is infact 4cm above where the bolt goes through the door. This seems to mean most roller fittings won't fit the door.

Can anyone recommend a replacement roller that'd fit this kind of door? I've searched amazon and various other sites but nothing has come up yet (UK, if that matters tho right now I'd order internationally if something worked).

[image]

Comment: That is a typical "barn door" type set up where the track is above the opening. Considering the effort that goes into making shower door hardware, it's possible that this is a bespoke piece and that you won't find a replacement without going to the original manufacturer. You may need to look into repairing this or, perhaps, getting a replacement custom made (3D printing, anyone?) instead of finding a ready made replacement.

Comment: I was afraid you might say that @FreeMan. I suspect this might not of been a shower door coupling in the first place, as a lot of things in this house have been.... ingeniously used lets say. :D

Comment: I'm not implying that this wasn't designed from the factory like this, just giving that type of setup a name for you. It _is_ a bit unusual in shower door hardware, but by no means totally unique in the world. This may have been sold with "hangs like a barn door!!" as a value added feature instead of bodged by a previous DIY. To be fair, though, it does appear that the top of the wheel is pulled outward because there's no top track to contain it, so there's extra stress on the shaft & mount for it.

Comment: I do see some bearings inside the wheel on top. Maybe you can find a way to press the wheel off, inspect it and the race for wear, then replace/repack the bearings. If the race isn't too badly damaged, this may be fixable.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks for your comments - that's my exact plan now - however the 'bottom' of the door doesn't attach in anyway. It had some simular clips (which just protruded out and appear to are meant to 'slot' under a rail at the bottom, however they've never been in the bottom rail and are in fact broken off entirely.
I am planning to try replacing the wheels (and I have some already).

Comment: So the race (presuming this is the chanel the bearings run in, is fine. However the bearings themselves are shot. https://i.imgur.com/cVm3RJt.png - one is entirely gone, the other is cracked. I got some bearings from amazon, 23mm seemed to be the largest, yet they aren't large enough. And the bearings that are in situ seem to be a combination bolt and bearing, i.e. not replacable without getting something identical. I'm now entirely stuck on how to fix this :(

Comment: Pro Tip™: Amazon is _not_ the only retailer left in the world. Try someone else - somewhere very plain and boring looking, with a lot of company/contractor trucks in the parking lot and no glitzy web-site. Bring the parts in with you and humbly ask for help...

Comment: Someones just suggested to me (on discord) to try searching for screw nylon bearing - this is what I needed to be searching for - I had searched other DIY places in the UK, but most are just useless.... and I was searching for the wrong thing it seemed anyway :)